# Horror anthology about vampires and werewolves. "If i cut my nails will you give me more meat?" a child asks his parents, in one story

Tags: story-identification, books, horror

this book has mini stories inside and has one story about a kid who gets invited to dinner and a boy is let out of the basement and eats and then says to his parents "If i cut my nails, will you give me more meat?"

Comment: When did you read this book? In what language? Do you recall the cover, name of characters, any other stories from it? See also our guide "https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/4918" for more on how you could improve this question.